# How to retrieve more accurate location in Android

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

Hello I am trying to make a tracking type of mobile application. I need to require GPS points latitude and longitude more accurate.

As you know we can get the location points using two methods in Android.

*First approach* : Use [Location API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and get live location points. Here is the dummy code to do

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

As I have set the `GPS_PROVIDER` to get more accurate location and set the `minTime` value to 0 and minimum distance between location updates value to 0

*Second approach* : To get the location using the Google Play services APK that use fused location provider to retrieve locations points

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

    // Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(
                LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 0 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        ...
    }

    ...
    // Define the callback method that receives location updates
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    ...
}
```

So both do same thing to retrieve locations in Android. I tried to use same concept of Google Play Service to do Geo Fence but that is not working for me accurately.

Anyway, I have question that which approach is considered as best now to retrieve more accurate locations and should work in all environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "more accurate?"  GPS should be accurate to a few meters.  Do you need it to be more accurate than that?

Comment: Fused location API is more or less just the regular Location API just with an easier to use API that manages all the location providers for you

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you ever worked using `Location API` that mostly time give a location that is far from the current location like 500 to 700 meter. When I try to set it to more accurate then `onLocationChanged` method does not call

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, unless Android is deliberately misrepresenting the data.  Even when the government was deliberately throwing off the timing calculations for consumer GPS, it was still accurate to about 100 meters.  If your question is why `onLocationChanged` is not firing, ask about that.

Comment: @Williams so check and see if your GPS is turned on, you cannot get more accurate than GPS and your accuracy can vary depending on where you are in relation to the satellites and even your device

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you are inside a building, for example, GPS does not work, hence it will give you no location at all. The fused provider tries to address this issue.

Comment: @tyczj yes I checked that GPS is ON of my device

Comment: Just trying to help, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> have question that which approach is considered as best

This is really close to being an opinion based answer, but I consider the fused provider to be a better way to go because of its improved technology over `LocationManager`. It not only manages which provider is the best for the current state of the phone, but it also adds sensors in order to give a more accurate result. You cannot get more accurate than GPS, but if GPS is not available, the fused provider will try to get the best location possible.

> should work in all environment.

You are not guaranteed that either of them will work in all environments. Saying so, one of the main reasons Google released the fused provider was to tackle the fact that GPS does not work everywhere (i.e. inside buildings). So they used other providers (WiFi, network, etc) along side sensors to give the best location possible.

Comment: As we do to retrieve location from Cell Tower Points when app fails to get location using GPS and it is OFF so should I need to do same in this also or this is all done by Google Play Service ??